# flutter firebase error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception"

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

**project/build.gradle**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

**In app/build.gradle**

**line no.24** apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "blablabla.com"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**In pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_database: ^2.0.2
  firebase_core: ^0.3.1+1
  timeago: ^2.0.10
```

**Im getting this error**

```
$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you
get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with       
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                             2.2s 
Resolving dependencies...                                               
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process
"C:\Users\Krishnaganesh\Desktop\flutter_blog_app-master\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file
'C:\Users\Krishnaganesh\Desktop\flutter_blog_app-master\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or
--debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
  Command:
  C:\Users\Krishnaganesh\Desktop\flutter_blog_app-master\android\gradlew  .bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

How to solve this Error ...???

Comment: I'd suggest you migrate your project to AndroidX and try again

Answer (score 0):

Bump dependencies versions:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

```
  firebase_database: ^3.1.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.2+1
```

In *app/build.gradle* add these:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true // add this
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // add this
}
```

Don't forget to create `google-services.json` file in app/ folder and fill it with your data ([docs link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file)) or use some mock (like [this one](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mock-google-services.json)):

```
{
  "project_info": {...},
  "client": [...],
}
```